# A Riley, in Song!

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay

Should Puuuuzling be forgot and not, broooo-ought to this siiiiiiiite (please shorten),

And middle full of glowing leeeegs,

And end, Alor to flyyyyyyyyyyyyyy!

(Did I mention this shows the way?)

(It’s a riley, sung to the tune of Auld Lang Syne.)

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: This is a traditional riley riddle.